# Curl/php: execution time?

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

Using CURL/PHP, how can I measure server's execution time? and what is the diference b/w STARTTRANSFER_TIME and PRETRANSFER_TIME ?

Comment: Are you talking about the execution time of the server that runs the CURL code or the other server that's being called by CURL? If it is the other server, I would say that it is not possible to get an execution time - what you can calculate is a response time (which includes network latency)

Comment: am talking about the server that host the pasge am requestion: by execution time I mean the time that the server puts calculation the result that am requestion!

Comment: The answer provided by @DaveRandom would give you the time it tool _your_ server to get the response. Try comparing that to the `total_time` reported back from CURL. Also info about difference in [STARTTRANSFER_TIME and PRETRANSFER_TIME](http://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2008-10/0054.html)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding STARTTRANSFER_TIME and PRETRANSFER_TIME.

**Starttransfer_time**

> Pass a pointer to a double to receive the time, in seconds, it took
>   from the start until the first byte is just about to be transferred.
>   This includes CURLINFO_PRETRANSFER_TIME and also the time the server
>   needs to calculate the result

**Pretransfer_time**

> Pass a pointer to a double to receive the time, in seconds, it took
>   from the start until the file transfer is just about to begin. This
>   includes all pre-transfer commands and negotiations that are specific
>   to the particular protocol(s) involved

Comment: @ProXamer Please accept the answer if helpful thanks! :)